# Test if an index of a list exists

Tags: python

Okay, so this is actually two questions. First, I want to know if there is a way to test if an index of a list exists. For example, I want to increment list[i] each time a given condition is true using code like `list[i] += 1`, but if the index doesn't exists, I'm given an error. So I want to set up a test that, in the case of an error, does something like `list.append(1)`. What code could accomplish such a testing condition? `If list[i]` throws an error.

As a follow up question, once the test is established, is there any way to create a list index aside from using the aforementioned append method?

Comment: you can use `try..except` and capture `IndexError`, inside except you can append the list

Comment: @avasal this is not what exceptions are made for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is a `defaultdict` -- not a list so much as a mapping of integers to some sort of count of the number of times you've seen them.

(this is really close to the concept of autovivificaiton in perl, if you've used that before)

This code would work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# don't name a variable 'list'; you'll end up hiding the actual list type
my_List = defaultdict(int) # create a mapping, elements will default to 0
```

Then you can use

```
my_list[i] += 1
```

for *any* value of `i`. If it has been seen before, then it will increment it. If not, then `my_list[i]` will get a default value of 0, which will immediately be incremented to 1.

Answer (score 7):

Test if an index exists:

```
if 0 <= i < len(list): ... do something with list[i] ...
else: ... i is out of bounds, do something else ...
```

In this situation, you're probably better off using a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instead of an array, and possibly a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to create a list index aside from using the aforementioned append method?

Yes with the [`Range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) method.

```
indexList = range(len(nameList))  # create a list of indexes
print "Index list:", indexList

for i in indexList:            # Pick items out of the list
    print ">>>", nameList[i]
```

Best way to test for `null` variables in python is... (It is very important that `None` is Uppercase and not lowercase).

```
if list[i] != None: #check if there is something there
    print "Oh hello... " + list[i]
else:
    print "Nothing to see here, move along"
```

Answer (score 1):

> First, I want to know if there is a way to test if an index of a list
>   exists.

You can take advantage of the fact that list indices are numeric (starting from 0), and are recalculated when lists are modified:

```
if i <= len(mylist):
   print mylist[i]
```

The other way, to avoid the `IndexError` is to catch it:

```
try:
  mylist[i] += 1
except IndexError:
  print "No item at ", i
```

> is there any way to create a list index aside from using the
>   aforementioned append method?

You don't "create" an index, it is automatically set when you add or delete items from a list.  So the only way to create an index is to append an item to the list.

Usually it is a flag of bad design if you are constantly "pre-setting" your list - that is, you set a large list with a default value and then step through that.

Comment: It should be if i < len(mylist) your check is off by one so it'd fail at the end of a list.